# Naming convention of callback in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, naming-conventions

Is there a naming convention for the name of the callback function you pass to async methods in node.js? I've seen a number of different names used and I generally pick a name that makes sense in the given context.

Has a convention emerged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are no general naming convention. I use a normal speaking name in camelCase. My co-worker prefers the `Callback` postfix like `handleUserListCallback`. My other co-worker prefers the `Handler` postfix and another prefers the __ *(double underscore)* prefix *(yes he was a python believer)*.

For naming the variable: Name it clearly.

```
function fetch(parameter, callback) {}
function worker(parameter, done) {}
function job(parameter, finish) {}
```

Try to use an understandable naming. One that you can understand and other who tries to read or improve your code and be consequent.

Comment: This answer is pretty sensible.  As a follow-up, you may want to check out this link: http://callbackhell.com/.  The author describes worst-case scenarios with using callbacks in node, and he even suggests naming your anonymous functions.

Comment: Btw callbacks. I try to use promises if I can instead of callback-to-callback-to-callback in node.

Comment: I feel prefixing is with "handle" is more descriptive rather than "callback" which is too vague

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is no strict convention for that. I'll go with the context based names like for example:

```
var updateUserInDB = function(userUpdated) {
   // ... logic here
   userUpdated();
}
updateUserInDB(function() {
   // ... ah, it's done
});
```

If you can't come up with a name then use `callback`. It will be perfectly clear what is the parameter about. Actually I'm usually using both methods. So, something like `userUpdatedCallback` will work better in the example above.